# Configuring GitKraken to push/fetch w/ Github

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I am trying to configure GitKraken with a particular repo I have on Github.  As far as I can tell, once I give it my local project folder with the repo, it can see the remote.  However, trying to push or pull gives me an error `Push/Fetch failed.  could not connect to origin`.

It seems like it is an issue with authentication and SSH.  I've tried to generate public/private keys in GitKrakens preferences auth page and add them to Github under the Github pane, but I get the same errors.

At this point I simply can't get things to work.  I'm unfamiliar with the specifics of SSH.  What is the issue here and how can I configure GitKraken to push/fetch with my upstream?

Comment: Check that your origin URL is correct. It should be something like `git@github.com/...` If you want to use SSH. If you don't want to use SSH, you can just use HTTPS, change your remote to point to the HTTPS URL.

Comment: The fetch/push urls are correct.  It just occurred to me that it may be a permissions thing because this is a private repo on a Team.  And although the SSH keys configured in my terminal are fetch/pushing, the SSH keys GitKraken generated might need to be authorized by a Team Admin.. possible no?

Comment: I have the same issues on ubuntu inside a virtualbox.

Comment: I solved it.  The fix was to set my repo to use an SSH url instead of https.  I guess GitKraken was only compliant with SSH?  anyway i was configuring it s SSH settings and not using it in the repo, so a bit of a silly mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitKraken won't let me clone from a private repo on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945280/gitkraken-wont-let-me-clone-from-a-private-repo-on-github)

Answer (score 61):

I also had this issue. Because I was trying to pull an organizations repo which was also private I needed to be granted access by the organization to use GitKraken (since it is seen as a third-party). If you go to your Github settings and under **Applications -> Authorized OAuth App -> GitKraken** thats where you can apply for permissions to the specific organizations you are assigned to on Github.

Hope this helps!

[image: How to get to the GitKraken OAuth screen]

[image: Clicking grant next to an organisation/team]

Comment: This is what I was running into, needed to grant access to the org too. Thanks Faris

Comment: This was the fix for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Faris, exactly what i needed

Comment: Might not be clear from the above screenshot: make sure to click on the "GitKraken" link in order to be able to "Request" from your org.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. It occurred right after i got back from vacation. The issue was reproducible with one specific repo. It seemed that the GitKraken was not able to remember my GitHub credentials despite the settings I used. I tried both:

**File -> Preferences -> Authentication -> GitHub -> enter my credentials**

and

execute **Pull** command on a branch and enter the credentials there and check the *Remember me* checkbox.

Both approaches did not work for me.

However, I resolved the issue by deleting the local repo and then **File -> Clone Repo -> select GitHub.com tab -> enter credentials**

the clone operation succeeded and GitKraken now remembers me and I can once again work with it as I used to.

Comment: This is very inefficient as git repo are usually initialized by third party. Should be reported as a bug

Answer (score 0):

Remove third party access restrictions in GitHub.
[image]