# GitKraken won't let me open my Private Repository on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitkraken

So, in addition to [GitKraken won't let me clone from a private repo on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945280/gitkraken-wont-let-me-clone-from-a-private-repo-on-github)
I get this screen when opening my GitLab Repo:

[image: notification I get after opening my Repo]

Anyone got a solution of how to make my Repo 'non-private' or how to make GitKraken let me open this without the Pro Plan?

Already tried:

- Generating new SSH Key in GitKraken
- Removing Repo, Generate new GitLab connection, Clone Repo
- Checked GitLab: GitKraken is an Authorized applications
- Git Pull via command line gives no trouble, so no permission issue
- ...

Comment: If possible can you try making the repository public. Clone the repository. Open it and then make it private again?

Comment: Making the whole repo public should not be an option and I rather don't do that. I'm hoping someone encountered the same thing and has a working solution :/

Comment: This  really sucks. i'm switching to sourcetree. sigh...

Comment: I tested on 2022-Juli and got the same error. Despite all advertisement "Free" it's NOT free if you have private REPO. I uninstalled and revoked all GIT permissions in my repo. If they want to charge they're stuff, ok. But don't say "is free" when is not. GitKraken for me never more.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**6.5.1** is the last version to support private repo. You can see the release details at this link https://blog.axosoft.com/gitkraken-v6-0/#pricing-changes OR https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/6x/

And you can also download it (Mac version) from Axosoft https://release.axocdn.com/darwin/GitKraken-v6.5.1.zip OR https://release.gitkraken.com/darwin/GitKraken-v6.5.1.zip

I not sure how to turn off the automatic update function, so if you turn off GitKraken completely and reopen it, it will update to the latest version.

=======

Updated

Block IP Address for updating

For MacOS

`echo "127.0.0.1 release.gitkraken.com" >> /private/etc/hosts`

[image]

1. Windows 10 – “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts”
2. Linux – “/etc/hosts”
3. Mac OS X – “/private/etc/hosts”

Comment: For windows folks: https://release.gitkraken.com/win64/GitKrakenSetup-6.5.1.exe

Comment: For Linux users - https://release.axocdn.com/linux/GitKraken-v5.0.4.deb

Comment: Latest for linux: https://release.axocdn.com/linux/GitKraken-v6.5.1.deb

Comment: Does this still work? I still get the private repo message from 6.5.1

Comment: As of today 2022, this thing is not working.

Comment: Anyone has got new links?

Comment: GitKraken has announced it will discontinue support for legacy versions of client 6.6.0 and older :(
https://www.gitkraken.com/blog/discontinuing-access-and-support-for-gitkraken-client-6-6-0-and-older

Comment: Anywhere third-party to get old GitKraken versions?

Comment: Yes, not working anymore. Is it possible to make a mock server?

Answer (score 26):

Installing older version of Gitkraken is the only solution I guess to work on private repo if you want it for free and without student developer pack.

From the release notes, the last version to support private repo is v6.5.1.

Download link:

For windows: https://release.gitkraken.com/win64/GitKrakenSetup-6.5.1.exe

For linux (debian): https://release.axocdn.com/linux/GitKraken-v6.5.1.deb

For linux (tar.gz): https://release.axocdn.com/linux/GitKraken-v6.5.1.tar.gz

For mac: https://release.axocdn.com/darwin/GitKraken-v6.5.1.zip

Comment: For mac: 404 not found

Answer (score 20):

Download old version of app
[Official download URL](https://release.gitkraken.com/darwin/GitKraken-v5.0.4.zip) for macOS. For Win you have link on Comments in this answer

[image]

## EDIT:

OMG! I found it.
There is auto patcher who was build over yarn
https://github.com/5cr1pt/GitCracken
Work like a sharm

### Note:

It take a decent time to install, so be patient.

Comment: Is there an option to disable auto-update? The problem with the version I used was that it auto-updated the next time I opened GitKraken. Thanks for checking, this is the better solution for sure!

Comment: Since i install i hade no problem with that, it’s like app won’t autoupdate. I know that was problem for prev versions. I will lt you know all if this old version auto update

Comment: Do you have a link for Windows too? Simply adding win64 or windows does not work :)

Comment: add to hosts
127.0.0.1 release.gitkraken.com

Comment: @Eagle_ yesterday GitKraken update by himself. 1 year ago i was searching for solution but with no luck, basically all people are said that it's not possible to block auto update. 
But i try another solution and we will see how this will manage, in Security & Privacy under Firewall tab i add GitKraken and block all incoming connections.I will let you know all if this work or not!

Comment: @Eagle_ no luck, every time i close GitKraken he autoupdate. To be precise, on first startup, he download latest update :-(
Only solution is to not close app at all :-D

Comment: @Stefan I am pretty sure I found this solution to disable the update somewhere here in the comments - cant find it anymore so now I post it: On Windows GitKraken 6.5.1 installs itself under C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\gitkraken . There is the file Update.exe - I renamed that to Update.exe.delete and changed all my shortcuts to the actual application in the subfolder app-1.5.1 . For me it worked - hope there is a similar way on macOS.

Comment: For windows user, [GitKraken 6.5.1](https://release.axocdn.com/win64/GitKrakenSetup-6.5.1.exe) is a better choice

Comment: I found it! Best solution ever!
There is auto patcher
https://github.com/5cr1pt/GitCracken

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, this what I found:

[They say](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/d5cbsy/so_suddenly_git_kraken_wont_open_private/f0l5bdo), and I quote -

> This was a licensing change we made 3 months ago. When we made the
> change, we gave all existing users a 3 month free trial, which are all
> expiring this week. Sounds like yours is one of them

**BTW** worth noting that if you're a student, you can use GitKraken for free:
https://www.gitkraken.com/student-resources

Comment: Doesn't help, but it is the sad truth... Started using Sourcetree a while ago and so far so good.

Answer (score 14):

My solution is to uninstall GitKraken and install [Fork](https://git-fork.com/), a very similar program with all the options that I have used previously in GitKraken. It's free and has a dark mode too :-)

Comment: Fork seems to be as powerful as GitKraken yet less pretty, even if it has a dark mode. It will do the job for the moment, but when you go to the download page, you'll see "Free, $49.99 soon". Not sure if it means that it soon won't be free anymore.

Comment: Yes, Fork won't be free anymore in the near future. But the price $49.99 (exluding tax) will be for 3 computers and it doesn't matter if it is used for commercial purposes or not

Comment: Source tree is also a good solution

Answer (score 8):

(window users)
In your `%appdata%/../Local/gitkraken`, remove latest gk version you just updated, remove updater & use the previous version (& maybe buy a license)

Comment: Did you find any solution for Mac user?

Answer (score 7):

(Windows solution)

I think this solution should work:

- Since **Private repo** is moved to paid plan after v6.5.1 so make sure you **download** an earlier version (For example [Windows: 5.0.4](https://release.gitkraken.com/win64/GitKrakenSetup-5.0.4.exe) - Change version number to any desired one)
- If you had a newer version installed, get rid of it like this:

  - Uninstall that version
  - Go to `C:/Users/USERNAME/appdata/local/` and remove `GitKraken`
  - Go to `C:/Users/USERNAME/appdata/roaming/` and remove `.gitkraken`
- Install the selected older version
- Go to `C:/Users/USERNAME/appdata/local/gitkraken` and rename `Update.exe` to `Update_.exe` (Don't remove it. Needed for uninstalling)
- Use it

> **Note**: **I had issues with some repos even with this solution** and that **could be because gitkraken saves config file in the repo** (which is not shared with remote). So make sure you **remove the local project and get it from remote again**.

(**Note**: Newer version obviously contains more features. You may want to purchase a license to be updated and fine, as well as supporting the company)

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried running GitKraken 6.5.1 on a recent version of Ubuntu, you have probably noticed that it has dependencies that can't be satisfied (gvfs-bin). However, you can run it in Docker by building an image for it based on Ubuntu 18.04!

Download the GitKraken package:

```
wget https://release.axocdn.com/linux/GitKraken-v6.5.1.deb
```

Create a Dockerfile. Replace YOURUSERNAME with your local username. Replace 1000 with your actual user and group IDs respectively:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY GitKraken-v6.5.1.deb /tmp
RUN apt update && apt install gconf2 gconf-service libgtk2.0-0 libnotify4 libxtst6 libnss3 libxkbfile1 python gvfs-bin xdg-utils xauth libxss1 libasound2 -y
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/GitKraken-v6.5.1.deb
RUN groupadd -g 1000 YOURUSERNAME && useradd -u 1000 -g 1000 YOURUSERNAME
CMD ["/usr/bin/gitkraken", "--no-sandbox"]
```

Build the Docker image:

```
docker build -t gitkraken .
```

Allow Docker to connect to your local XServer:

```
xhost +local:docker
```

Run your GitKraken in a container, mapping your local home directory into the container. Again, replace your username and IDs:

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --network=host -v /home/YOURUSERNAME:/home/YOURUSERNAME --user 1000:1000 gitkraken
```

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall and use an older version of gitkraken. V5.0.4 will continue to work as always.

Comment: download link below :D

Comment: @Stefan, I dont see any link.

Comment: @J.Doe Look at my answer below this one. But here is a link https://release.gitkraken.com/darwin/GitKraken-v5.0.4.zip

Comment: @Stefan, how do I use that file for Linux?  Is 5.0.4 the last free version?

Comment: @J.Doe Every version is free, just you can't load Private repo anymore. Try this one, they have v4. I'm not familiar with Linux, so, sorry if i miss lead you
https://snapcraft.io/gitkraken

Comment: Yea, I meant free for private repo.  Is there a listing of all versions?

Answer (score 2):

Gitkraken does not update automatically in Linux, so Axosoft can't shove it down your throat.  For Windows, there's SourceTree.  Consolations to Mac users.

Answer (score 0):

I have the GitKraken individual plan and can only use my account on one computer.
My laptop displays the same message regarding the private repository and blocks me. I thought that the individual plan would allow my single account on multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using GitKraken free version for more than an year. I ran into the same issue recently. I was able to get it working by reinstalling an older version.

Note: You need to do this whenever you restart your computer or Gitkraken.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Remove the latest version from (window users) appdata%/../Local/gitkraken
2. Create a short cut to the folder where the previous version is installed.
3. Open shortcut
4. Start executable.

What happens when the update come up again. I will see then.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a solid Git linux client, try GitClient, they have an AppImage,

it doesnt have all features of Kraken but very solid,

https://github.com/francescmm/GitQlient

Answer (score -1):

1. Save your files of Repository - Without Folder (.git)
2. Create new public repository
3. Copy and Commit your Files
4. Open your Repo (Git Kraken).

Comment: you must not use it if want you keep repository history!

Answer (score -3):

To expose your project from gitlab, go to Settings => General and select public under the ["Visibility, project features, permissions"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPgZo.png) section.
To open a private repo under GitKraken, [subscribe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN0YV.png) to their licence.

Comment: This used to work before without the paid plan but now I get this popup for some reason. I still want to find out why...