# How to install the old Gitkraken using `pkg.tar.gz` file?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I unwittingly updated Gitkraken from 5.0.4 on my Linux machine.  Just like this [dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095592/gitkraken-wont-let-me-open-my-private-repository-on-gitlab), I was in for a nasty surprise: the newer Gitkraken is not free for individual use.

After spend much time looking around, I could only find this old Linux installation file `gitkraken-5.0.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/antergos/files/mirror/antergos/x86_64/gitkraken-5.0.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz/download).  It does not have `.configure` file.  Thus, I could not do anything with it.  Did anyone managed to get it working?  This could help others who fall for the update trap from `Axosoft`.

I managed to find the old `.deb` file and got it back to working order.  Did anyone manage to a copy online somewhere?  I am afraid to accidentally lose the local copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, download the old version. After a while of searching I found it at this archive, but your source seems to be the same:

```
wget http://ftp.vim.org/ftp/pub/ftp/os/Linux/distr/antergos/antergos/x86_64/gitkraken-5.0.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Unzip it and move the content of `/opt` into your `/opt` folder and do the same with the `/usr` folder respectively.

Last, you need to install a dependency:

```
apt update && apt install gconf2
```

*Note: works for me on Kali 2020.3 (which depends on Debian 9.3.0)*

Comment: Thanks!  I found the old deb somewhere.  It's like gold now.

Comment: You need the Windows version of 5.0.4 too? If so: you simply need to add a firewall rule to block the Update.exe from phoning home to the update servers. After that, the version will stay at 5.0.4 and all features remain free :) The old Windows version can be found much faster than the Linux one, shouldn't be a problem to get it somewhere...

Comment: Hi there, where can I find a usable Windows version of GKK?

Comment: Here you have an overview over nearly all versions: 
https://gitkraken.software.informer.com/versions/
https://gitkraken.software.informer.com/download/

There you can find the version you need :)

Answer (score 0):

[Update]

Since I came across this question so many times in the past to get my V-5.0.4, I thought this could be helpful to others as a heads up, since I found myself stuck on this for a couple of hours thinking it was a problem on my side;

> From February 28th 2023, versions **6.6.0 and older** ceased to function as announced in January 20th, 2023. More details [here](https://www.gitkraken.com/blog/discontinuing-access-and-support-for-gitkraken-client-6-6-0-and-older).

This doesn't affect the installation itself, but you will just find yourself facing a not-working login dialog that blocks the entire window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).