# Install old gitkraken version (5.0.4 from Antergos `pkg.tar.gz` file) on Ubuntu mate 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gitkraken, arch

I had the 4.2 version of gitkraken on my ubuntu mate 18.04. Yesterday I switched to ubuntu mate 22.04 and I couldn't be able to install the 4.2 version from the old .deb package I had.

I found this discussion [How to install the old Gitkraken using `pkg.tar.gz` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129237/how-to-install-the-old-gitkraken-using-pkg-tar-gz-file) .
I downloaded the file (gitkraken-5.0.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz) and I followed the instructions (install gconf2). But when I try to start gitkraken I get the start screen (with the kraken) but the software doesn't start. Starting it using the shell I get this message in the terminal : *state:  update-not-available*.
Is there a way to install this arch package on ubuntu or to convert it to a debian package??
Unfortunately this link https://release.axocdn.com/linux/GitKraken-v5.0.4.deb doesn't work anymore.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the current Ubuntu is no longer compatible with an olddated version of GitKraken? v4.2 is more than three years old

Comment: The version of the second package  (for arch) that I would like to install 5.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The instruction here or for Ubuntu 20.04 but also helped me install on to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.  https://gist.github.com/ivan-aksamentov/9e59de334c1e1b95f692f222db411f5a
Gave me a working version of GitKraken 9.1.1

tl;dr

```
wget https://release.axocdn.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -R gitkraken-amd64.deb gitkraken-amd64/
sed -i -E -e 's/, python,/, python \| python2,/g' gitkraken-amd64/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b gitkraken-amd64/ gitkraken-amd64.focal.deb
gdebi -nq gitkraken-amd64.focal.deb
```